# Company doesn't need me anymore, what to do?

Tags: resignation, careers, germany

I've been working at a company as a development lead for the past year. Everything was going great, only that now the business has given up on the project I was working on.

They've transitioned members of my team to other projects, but as those projects already have team leads it doesn't make financial sense for them to keep me around as a regular developer due to my salary.

Now they're giving me trivial tasks, such as updating documentation etc.  I've spoken to my supervisor and he has clarified that *"they don't have a place for me here"* and *"if he were me he would look for other options"*.

Another thing, I live in a European country where it's almost impossible to ask someone to leave, and the company has a ton of money - they can't pretend they can't afford me.

My obvious option is to resign, but I feel that it's giving up too easily. They've hired me with a promise to build a career here, and now they're expecting me to leave.

Is there a way to force a "Golden parachute"?

Comment: Did they tell you that they're expecting you to leave, or are you simply assuming? Might the company simply be having a bit of a dry spell? Why do you think that these people will never have another job for you to complete, ever? Why don't you take the proactive approach and go talk to your boss about a project you might possibly become a part of, or contribute to?

Comment: Golden Parachute according to [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_parachute)? This is generally something you have to negotiate *before* you sign the employment contract.

Comment: Location might be important here.

Comment: Why not straight up ask your boss whether the company is willing to pay you a severance package? If they refuse you could remain in your current position on their dime, doing trivial work, for months and months, while you look for the **_perfect job*_** (*rules and conditions apply). That's not necessarily a bad situation to be in, all things considered (better than not having a job and watching your saving shrink as you send out your resume, right?) As for it being fair .. well. Life isn't, and business even less so.

Comment: In France, we call it "to be put in the cupboard". As we have fairly strict legislation to fire people, it is often financialy/administratively easier to strongly suggest the employee quits by himself rather than fire him. That's maybe why you've been given menial tasks, and probably won't see a raise while you work here. However, if this leads to bullying and psychological presure, you have ground for a lawsuit. Make sure you document every occurence of it if that happens.

Comment: Does Germany not have redundancy laws based on your role not being needed for operational reasons?

Comment: "... they can't pretend they can't afford me." - Why do you think this matters in any way?  I can afford hair curlers, but being a balding man in my late 40's, it makes no economic sense for me to buy them.  Guess what you are to them, now?

Answer (score 9):

When you don't have work, find work.

Instead of waiting for a project to be assigned to you, actively try to come up with some project you could do and propose it to the management. This might be an idea for a new product, an enhancement to an existing product, or an improvement for an internal process.

If you can't find anything, you might want to look for work elsewhere.

Comment: I've been looking for a job and I have viable options. Although I feel that they've done wrong to me and shouldn't get away with it

Comment: @chiplax - There's no point holding on to your anger (_"they should't get away with it"_, etc.) They did what made the most sense from a financial perspective, and you should follow their example. Ask your boss for a severance package. If you get one, quit and find yourself a new job ASAP. If you're refused, then slowly look for a new job while living on their dime.

Comment: @chiplax They're still paying you. How are they "getting away"?

Answer (score 3):

[Note: This answer was written before the "Germany" tag was applied]

> Is there a way to force a "Golden parachute"?

No, in the US at least, that's not something you can force.

As you have indicated, the company doesn't need you anymore. Thus you have no leverage to force anything. Even in Germany I don't see you having enough leverage to force a golden parachute situation if your contract and local laws don't already have that in place.

You could attempt to negotiate something, if you think your boss and company are appreciate of your work and willing to be "nice".

You could try something like "Look, boss. I know that the project got cut and it seems that I'm the odd person out here. I'd like to help transition everyone to the new projects while I find my next job. Can we talk about a severance package where I get paid while I spend some weekday time job hunting?" (Or just a discussion about any kind of severance concession you would prefer.)

The risk is that they just say No and let you go. (Or perhaps in Germany continue to give you trivial tasks indefinitely).

Or you could just accept that these sorts of things happen, find your next job, give the appropriate notice, and leave.

Comment: His leverage would be to refuse to quit. Firing someone without good reason is hard and possibly expensive in Germany.

Comment: @kat0r: Surely, "we don't have any work for him to do" classifies as a good reason? How else would a company downsize in a recession, for example?

Comment: @R_Kapp financial difficulties can qualify as a reason, but they're far from that.

Comment: @R_Kapp I can't speak for Germany but in other European countries there is often a long process where the employee is make formally 'at risk' the company then has to help them find other jobs internally if possible and usually pay them for a pretty long time (either to do pointless work or on gardening leave). Finally after all this process they can be let go, but usually with at least a fairly good legally mandated severance package. Though as I said I can't speak specifically for Germany.

Comment: @R_Kapp: Yes, that would be a good reason. But: 1) differently to the US with at-will, it is on the employer to proof that the reason was good, not on the employee to proof that it was a bad firing. And litigation is expensive. 2) "we don't have any work for him to do" requires the employer to proof that there really IS no work for him to do. If there are similar openings in the company, in a larger company, they can't do that convincingly.

Comment: @R_Kapp No. You have a duty to train the employee for other tasks if they're suited to it. He could be trained as a (overpaid but still) developer. Thats why they haven't laid him off yet. In essence he can sit on whatever tasks they give him as long as he bloody pleases. And unless the company goes through some ridiculous financial difficulty, they can't fire him. They can't even fire him because there's no work for a team lead. He could be a developer, and they're required to give him that before being able to fire.

Comment: oh @R_Kapp and mandating a pay cut is also not possible unless the company can show serious financial difficulties.

Comment: Sorry, downvoted: that's the correct answer for the US, but not for Germany where employees have significantly more leverage

Comment: @Magisch: As a team leader, he shouldn't need any training really for a developer position.

Answer (score 2):

I get you are expensive and they don't need any development leads right now.

But it sure makes more sense for them to use you as a regular programmer rather than trivial tasks.

Sure seems like they are encouraging you to resign.

You are costing them money. It would make financial sense for them to offer you a severance package.

Not sure how long you have been doing trivial tasks but I would stick with it for  a few months for negotiating position.  Then when you go to them and ask for a severance package they know the trivial tasks alone are not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force a "Golden parachute"?

## No

No, there is not. While there *may* be the chance that upon laying you off you may get a severance package, this is not guaranteed by law. They only give it to people because the severance package costs them less then the risk of a lawsuit.

While your company has to prove certain things when laying you off in Germany (like there was no other job for you at the company), there is *no* obligation for your company to provide you with a *career*. You have a job you are suited for and you get paid the same amount of money as before. This is as good as it gets. After all, they did not lay you off.

A word of personal advice: this opportunity is gone. It's over. Anything you do from now on is looking back and living in the past. Look forward, find a new job and proceed with your life and career. Right now, you will probably get good references and you will probably be able to negotiate anything you want concerning your notice period. Use this chance to leave there on good terms. The best way to show them they were wrong to let you go is to be productive, successful and happy at another company.

The only "golden" thing you get is that your current employer *has* to give you time off for your future interviews. However, seeing your bosses reaction, I guess that would not have been a problem anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you signed an employment contract that includes such a clause, you are not getting anything golden from your employer. ( *No golden parachute* )

I would suggest you begin your job search post haste.  I would find a job **first** before tendering your resignation.  Continue to keep doing what you are asked in the meantime without complaining.

Also, be sure to give the required notice so you don't burn any bridges when you leave.

**UPDATE**: As you have added input with a comment, you **definitely** need to work on your exit strategy by *moving on to your next job*.

Comment: Can you elaborate the exit strategy that you have in mind?

Comment: @chiplax The strategy is already outlined in my answer.  Its sadly time for you to move on.  It sucks what happened to you, but I don't think you'll get any concessions, and it probably isn't a good thing for you to stay mentally.  I updated my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on what type of company you are working for (government vs private) and what type of Union (or Personalrat) setup you have.

While you can't really force anything, you can certainly try to suggest a solution that's "mutually beneficial". Your benefit: cash in your pocket. Their benefit: you leave without making a fuzz which can safe them lots of effort, time, aggravation & money

That needs to be communicated carefully, since you don't want it to be an open threat and ideally everyone can keep face. Example

> "We both know that I'm not a good fit here anymore, so I'm
>   considering alternatives. It would be great could devote my full
>   effort to finding alternatives but I can't do this while I'm still
>   giving my best here. If you could provide financial support for, say,
>   six month after my departure, I could effectively engage in my next
>   step a we could mutually agree to end my employment here."

Comment: This is the right answer, imo. Joe's is good for the US, but in europe, the employee generally has a lot of leverage. It's important to use that leverage with tact and without flaunting it in people's faces.

Comment: That's it. He will stay in a dead-end job, but for full salary, until one side moves. If he moves first by finding a new job and quitting -> no money. If the company moves first by laying him off -> money in his pocket.